# How to check if a certain period of time passes an exact timestamp?

Tags: java

How do i check if a period of time(consisting of two temporal timevalues(start and end)) passes for example midnight ?

Im trying to use the LocalDateTime class, but can't seem to find anything usefull there..

Comment: What about `if( start < midnight && end > midnight)` (pseudo code)? Hint: use methods `isBefore` and `isAfter`.

Comment: All timestamps are before some midnight and after some midnight.

Comment: Check JodaTime or Calendar for date-time convenience.

Comment: Are you using Joda time or Java 8 version of LocalDateTime?

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I can come up with:

```
public static boolean passesTime(LocalDateTime start,
                                 LocalDateTime end,
                                 LocalTime time) {

    // If the duration is more than a day, any time will be passed.
    if (Duration.between(start, end).toDays() >= 1)
        return true;

    // Otherwise, the time has to be passed on the start day...
    LocalDateTime timeOnStartDay = LocalDateTime.of(start.toLocalDate(), time);
    if (timeOnStartDay.isAfter(start) && timeOnStartDay.isBefore(end))
        return true;

    // or on the end day.
    LocalDateTime timeOnEndDay = LocalDateTime.of(end.toLocalDate(), time);
    if (timeOnEndDay.isAfter(start) && timeOnEndDay.isBefore(end))
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Tested with the `java.time` API. If you're using Joda time the code should be similar (if not identical).